# How to make zsh-autocorrect insert common "prefix" instead of common "substring"?

Tags: plugins, tabs, zsh, key-bindings, zsh-completion

## TLDR

How can I configure `zsh-autocomplete` to insert up to the longest common prefix, excluding their common suffixes?

I have not seen this asked before on StackOverflow. [Here is a GitHub issue which is related but not the same.](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/issues/35)

---

## Setting up the problem

I have a directory with the following files:

```
❯ ls -1
foo_a.sh
foo_b.sh
```

With the [`zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) enabled (branch `main` -> commit `6d059a3`), typing `ls f` shows the following:

```
❯ ls f
file
foo_a.sh  foo_b.sh
common substring: foo_.sh
```

Note `common substring: foo_.sh`, which comes from `zsh-autocomplete`. This "common substring" consists of the prefix `foo_` and suffix `.sh` common to all files in the directory.

Pressing tab inserts that "common substring" into my command:

```
❯ ls foo_.sh  # cursor is now at the end after h
file
foo_a.sh  foo_b.sh
```

## The problem

That completion is not useful at all, because it also inserts the suffix. There is no file called `foo_.sh`!

Now I have to identify the disambiguating characters between the prefix and suffix, figure out where in the "common substring" they must be inserted, arrow back to that position, insert them, then arrow back to the end to continue the command.

That's a lot of work. Who wants that?

## The desired behavior

Much better would be to have tab insert only the common *prefix*:

```
❯ ls foo_
file
foo_a.sh  foo_b.sh
```

Then I just need to add `a` or `b`, and a second tab will complete the rest of the filename. No need to move my cursor back and forth.

By the way, I believe that this is the default tab completion behavior in zsh. For some reason, `zsh-autocomplete` seems to override it.

How can I configure `zsh-autocomplete` to work the same way?